# position of Prefab Cardboard change on Unity play

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I have problem with the Cardboard plugin for Unity 3d (the last one with IOS support)

I place the camera in the right place but when i press play to test it, the camera change of orientation and position.

how can I definite the rigth position and orientation on start ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, i use Prefab Cardboard Head instead Cardboard main

now it work great, thank you :D